# sentencia if shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia a todos, necesito obtener validaciones de la siguiente manera, y esto es lo que he hecho:

```
 ClassDiv: stock.Wder == "" ? "inactive" : stock.End == "" && stock.Insp == "" && stock.Req == "" && stock.Insp == "" ? "white" : stock.Insp == "" && stock.Insp == "" ? 'red' : stock.Insp != "" && stocks.Insp == "" ? 'yellow' : stock.Insp != "" && stock.Insp != "" ? 'red' : 'white',
```

El codigo que conozco normal es este, pero deseo obtener estas validaciones en el formato anterior:

```
if (stock.Insp == "" && stock.Insp == "" && item.endInspection == "" && stock.Req == "")
{
 ClassDiv = white;
}
else if (stock.Insp == "" && stock.Insp == "")
{
 ClassDiv = "red";
}
else if (stock.Insp != "" && stock.Insp == "")
{
 ClassDiv = "yellow";
}
else if (stock.Insp != "" && stock.startInsp != "")
{
 ClassDiv = 'green';
}
else
{
 ClassDiv = white';
}
```

Pueden apoyarme sobre como puedo resolver este detalle que tengo?

Comment: Podrías utilizar un switch case en lugar de los if https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch

Comment: No se si es problema al copiar y pegar o es que realmente esto lo tienes así:`else if (stock.Insp != "" && stock.Insp == "")`. Esta condición siempre será `false`.

Comment: Estudiando la lógica de tus proposiciones, la verdad no le veo mucho sentido. O yo estoy perdiendo algo que no veo claro o el problema está en que tienes un gran problema al asignar tu lógica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asignación ternaria!

Teniendo el siguiente código:

```
if (a > b){ 
    c=1 
}else{
    c=0
}
```

Su equivalente ternario es:
`c = a > b ? 1 : 0`

Explicado:

```
c = a > b ? 1 : 0
c =                // Con 'c'
    a > b ?        // Si 'a' es mayor que 'b'
            1      // asigna 1
              :    // Sino (else)
                0  // Asigna 0
```

Aplicado a tu `if` sería algo así:

```
ClassDiv = 
stock.Insp == "" && stock.Insp == "" && item.endInspection == "" && stock.Req == "" ? 'white'
: stock.Insp == "" && stock.Insp == "" ? 'red'
: stock.Insp != "" && stock.Insp == "" ? 'yellow'
: stock.Insp != "" && stock.startInsp != "" ?  'green'
: 'white'
```

Comment: Sé que está así en la pregunta, pero la primera condición está duplicada